How can I define a custom administrative role in an azure ad b2c tenant
First of all: I'm not talking about roles for users!
I'm talking about administrative roles used by the azure portal (or the entra admin center)
When I go to the "Roles & admins" page on the entra admin center for a regular entra id tenant, then I have the option to create a custom role:

(I know the button is disabled in the screenshot, but that's besides the point)
However, when I go to the same page for an azure AD B2C tenant, I don't seem to have that option:

Why is that? and is there a different way to define a custom administrative role in an azure ad b2c tenant?

Unfortunately, custom roles is not currently available for Azure AD B2C directories.
source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/roles-resource-access-control
